# Attempt to understand the Kaluza-Klein theory

Tags: general-relativity, kaluza-klein, unified-theories

I'm currently doing an internship on Kaluza-Klein theory. by reading some articles, I don't understand some things that seem easy to authors for example : In this article  https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9805018 — very good article writted by Wesson and Overduin — They said

- In page 7, <<
  ... In particular, one should be able to recover a “ground state” solution consisting of
  four-dimensional Minkowski space plus a d-dimensional compact manifold.
  Although **this is straightforward** when **d = 1** (Klein’s case) ... >>.
- In page 15 << The fact that the action (3) leads to (9)... with source matter, constitutes the central
  miracle of Kaluza-Klein theory. >> I don't see in the equation matter term, is it the electromagnetic tensor F ? or is it the scalar field (dilaton)?

Comment: Consider to make question formulation self-contained.